# Peculiar links in Newsletter subscription page

Tags: support, newsletter

Out of curiosity, I clicked See Sample Newsletter on the main site. At the bottom of the page that appears there are several links like this:

[image: Newsletter subscription links]

Some of these links go to Youtube videos instead of the subscription pages that you might expect.

Is this a bug or is my browser playing tricks? My browsers, I should say, as I have got the same result on both Internet Explorer and Firefox, and I have cleared the cache etc.

(I get the same results doing the same thing from the TeX.SE site, so it's not just Mathematics.)

The newsletter page in question may be seen [here](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I got the same result (Firefox).  One youtube video shows the "epic sax guy."

Comment: Can you also provide a link to the page?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I have added a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101334/links-in-newsletter-preview-link-to-youtube).

See Jeff Atwood's answer there. Essentially, the actual unsubscribe links can't be displayed in the example page. So they chose to put these youtube links.

Comment: Thanks. I must remember to search Meta as well as MathsMeta before asking a question.

Comment: Yeah, something like that was bound to appear on meta.SE sooner or later.